# EasyButton->how to change its location on map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a very simple question. I'm using EasyButton plugin of leaflet. But I can not change its location on map. For example how can I move the button to top right corner?

Here is my code:

```
   var toggle = L.easyButton ({
states: [{
stateName: 'remove-legend',
icon: '<span>masquer la légende</span>',
title: 'masquer la légende',
onClick: function(control) {
    map.removeControl(legend0);
} 
}, {
icon:'<span>voir la légende</span>',
stateName: 'add-legend',
  title: 'voir la légende' ,
  onClick: function(control) {
  if(map.getZoom()<12){  
        map.addControl(legend12);                   
        }
}]
});
toggle.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply add the `position` property, just like for other Leaflet controls:

```
var toggle = L.easyButton ({
  position: 'topright', // topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright
  //your code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But, one more thing: I want to put it below the layer control pane (that small square showing layers), how to do that? @afalciano

Comment: Add the layer control to map first, then the easyButton one. If they have the same position, their relative position depends by the order of loading.

Comment: @Gamze If my answer was useful, please consider also to vote it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a better alternative.

If the `Leaflet.EasyButton` persists at the default topleft position. Change it this way

```
ctlSidebar = L.control.sidebar('side-bar').addTo(mymap);

                ctlEasybutton = L.easyButton('glyphicon-transfer',function(){
                   ctlSidebar.toggle();
                }).setPosition('bottomright').addTo(mymap);
```

The key section is

```
.setPosition('bottomright').addTo(mymap);
```